# How to sort builds list by latest number in Experimental UI of Teamcity 2019.1

Tags: teamcity

In new Experimental UI of Teamcity 2019.1 at project overview page on Builds list tab builds aren't sorted.

[image]

I want to see it sorted by latest build number like it was in Classic UI.
How I can do it?